About perturbation bound for Cholesky factorization
I recently met the following problem about controlling the difference between Cholesky factors of two matrices when studying a problem in terms of estimating Cholesky factors from data.
For two symmetric positive definite matrices $A$ and $B$, suppose their Cholesky factorization $A=L_1L_1^{\top}, B=L_2 L_2^{\top}$.
If
\begin{equation}
\frac{\|A-B\|}{\|B\|}\le \epsilon,
\end{equation}
then what can we say about the difference between $L_1$ and $L_2$, in terms of epsilon and the condition number of $B$ ?
\begin{equation}
\frac{\|L_1-L_2\|}{\|L_2\|}\le ?
\end{equation}
Here the matrix norm is spectral norm.
Thanks for any possible ideas or comments!

The following two papers answered this question I posted:

On Parlett’s Matrix Norm Inequality for the Cholesky Decomposition, by Alan Edelman.

On the perturbation of the cholesky factorization, by Zlatko Drmac, Matjaz Omladic, and Kresimir Veselic.


In fact, one can prove the following:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\|L_1-L_2\|}{\|L_2\|}\le (2\log_2 M+4)\kappa(B)\frac{\|A-B\|}{\|B\|},
\end{align*}
where $\kappa(B):=\|B\|\|B^{-1}\|$ is the condition number of $B$, and $M$ is the size of the matrix.
In general, the prefactor $\log_2(M)$ cannot be removed due to the example provided in the above two papers.
Here the matrix norm is spectral norm.
